# Data ends up in wrong columns using SELECT and GROUP BY on result of LEFT-RIGHT-JOIN-UNION and LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I am an SQL newbie, sorry if the answer is obvious. Note that I have researched and tried to solve this for some 2h now. *Please read carefully before considering this question redundant.*

I would like to **join three tables**, **one** of which needs to be a **full join**, and then SELECT and GROUP BY on the result, such as here:

```
SELECT country, COUNT(DISTINCT customerNumber), SUM(priceEach*quantityOrdered) 
FROM orders 
LEFT JOIN orderdetails USING (orderNumber) 
FULL JOIN customers USING (customerNumber)
GROUP BY country;
```

Full joins are done with the UNION of a left and right join. Using SELECT and GROUP BY to calculate fields based on LEFT-RIGHT-JOIN-UNION and LEFT JOIN ***caused data to end up in the wrong columns in the final ouput***. This did not work:

```
SELECT country, COUNT(DISTINCT customerNumber), SUM(priceEach*quantityOrdered) 
FROM (SELECT * FROM orders LEFT JOIN customers USING(customerNumber)
      UNION
      SELECT * FROM orders RIGHT JOIN customers USING(customerNumber)) as ocFull
LEFT JOIN orderdetails USING (orderNumber) 
GROUP BY country;
```

I cannot figure out my error. What am I doing wrong? Alternatively, how is this usually done? Please help!

Comment: You forgot to tell what you are trying to achieve , and you should include sample data and desired outcome as text to clarify the explanation.

Comment: How do u include sample data for SQL? What I am trying to achieve: "I would like to join three tables, one of which needs to be a full join"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @P.Salmon I know this, but as far as I know it is not possible to include data for sql here. At least I have not seen anyone do it. It is the classicmodels DB from https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-sample-database.aspx

Comment: Not so , but you haven't explained what you are trying to achieve and expecting us to reverse engineer intent from non-working code is not going to get you far.

Comment: 'I would like to join three tables, one of which needs to be a full join' - is not what you are trying to achieve it's how you think something can be achieved. What you are trying to achieve might be for example I want to count the number of customers by country..

Comment: And to reiterate there is no FULL JOIN in mysql - you can emulate it using union and right join and you will find plenty of examples if you search for mysql emulate full join. If you can publish sample data and desired outcome I will look at again but otherwise I'm out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two solutions to this problem: making all fields in all SELECT statements explicit (naming them instead of using * ) **or** removing the GROUP BY statement. The first is the exact solution to my problem.

**Make fields explicit:**

```
SELECT country, COUNT(DISTINCT customerNumber) AS N_customers, SUM(priceEach*quantityOrdered) AS total_sales 
    FROM (SELECT country, customerNumber, orderNumber FROM orders LEFT JOIN customers USING(customerNumber)
          UNION
          SELECT country, customerNumber, orderNumber FROM orders RIGHT JOIN customers USING(customerNumber)) as ocFull
    LEFT JOIN orderdetails ON orderdetails.orderNumber = ocFull.orderNumber
    GROUP BY country;
```

**Remove GROUP BY:**
Curiously, removing the GROUP BY statement fixed the issue. It seems that this affects the field order prior to completing all the joins in some way, leading to some data appearing in the wrong columns.

```
SELECT *  FROM 
(SELECT * FROM orders LEFT JOIN customers USING(customerNumber)
      UNION
      SELECT * FROM orders RIGHT JOIN customers USING(customerNumber)) as ocFull
LEFT JOIN orderdetails USING (orderNumber);
```

Please note that if GROUP BY is removed, it no longer makes sense to COUNT(), SUM() etc., since this was intend to take place across countries, so the SELECT statement was reduced to *.

If you have a similar problem or would like to reproduce the issue, the classicmodels database in question was taken from: [mysqltutorial](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/getting-started-with-mysql/mysql-sample-database-aspx/)